# The relative Frobenius $\operatorname{Frob}_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism iff $X\to S$ is étale

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme over $S$, where $S$ is a scheme of characteristic $p$. I heard that we can prove that the relative Frobenius $\operatorname{Frob}_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism iff $X\to S$ is étale "by dévissage to $\mathbb{A}^n$".

If I understand correctly, this means that we would use the *théorème 3.1.2* in EGA III, which I show here for completeness.

[image]

However, I have absolutely no idea how we could use it.

Obs: I know that there exists another question here on Math.SE with the same title but mine is explicitly about using this argument of "dévissage to $\mathbb{A}^n$".

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the theorem you quote either, and I will confess that I'm frequently frustrated by authors saying something follows by dévissage without giving details.  But a proof is given in a link (https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/relative-frobenius/) from the similarly titled question you alluded to, and I think the reduction to $\mathbb A^r_S$ (in the corollary at the end) is the argument you're looking for.

Comment: @RaviFernando I indeed looked at this proof but I think this is it. There the author uses a reduction to $\mathbb{A}^r_S$ *after* proving that the Frobenius is an isomorphism if $X\to S$ is étale. Perhaps the dévissage is needed for the converse?

Comment: This is a sin of expository laziness that Grothendieck and his contemporaries - alas, still fallible! - are fond of. The word “dévissage” (French for “unscrewing”) refers both to the specific theorem you quote (or to one of many similar statements) and to the general sort of argument similar to that theorem. An argument “by dévissage” is one in which you use a series of formal/soft reduction steps to prove a general statement by looking at base cases (eg using noetherian induction, exact sequence arguments, and the like to reduce to the case of a simple sheaf on an irreducible variety)